# Apache HTTP Server dejó de funcionar

Tags: apache

Buen día, tengo un servidor con windows 2012 server, instalado xampp para php 7.4 en la unidad c y también instalado xampp para php 5.6 en la carpeta mis documentos. Ambos aplicativos en sus dieferentes versiones funcionan bien, el problema es que cada cada cierto tiempo muestra un mensaje de error para la version 5.6 de php, que dice:

Apache Http server dejó de funcionar. Para cada version de xampp se cambió los puertos de apache. Pero el error persiste. [image: Apache dejo de funcionar]

Contenido apache (error.log)

```
[Wed Aug 11 09:02:14.667753 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8948:tid 404] AH00428: Parent: child process 6548 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Wed Aug 11 09:02:14.812905 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 8948:tid 404] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Aug 11 09:02:14.850937 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8948:tid 404] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 11 09:02:14.850937 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8948:tid 404] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed Aug 11 09:02:14.850937 2021] [core:notice] [pid 8948:tid 404] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\users\\administrador\\documents\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Users/Administrador/Documents/xampp/apache'
[Wed Aug 11 09:02:14.871949 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8948:tid 404] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10516
[Wed Aug 11 09:02:15.190142 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 10516:tid 412] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Aug 11 09:02:15.279209 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 10516:tid 412] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Aug 11 09:02:15.317238 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10516:tid 412] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa los logs del apache que falla y el Visor de eventos de WIndows. Edita tu pregunta y añade lo que encuentres relacionado con ese fallo.

Comment: Gracias, esta editado el error.log en mi pregunta.

Comment: XAMPP y WAMPP son programas para el desarrollador, NO se recomienda usarlos para poner en producción en un servidor. Aparte de los logs del Apache, revisa los logs del EventViewer del Windows, algo ha de haber por ahí. En todo caso, instala el Apache Web Server y si tienes datos en el mysql del Xampp, toca migrarlos. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes dos instalaciones de XAMPP? Yo creo que ahí es donde pueden comenzar los problemas. Si es porque necesitas separar proyectos, eso se hace con [virtualhost](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/configurar-virtual-hosts-apache-windows.html) y no es tan complicado. Tal vez lo "difícil" podría ser [seleccionar versión de PHP](https://qastack.mx/programming/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp) para cada sitio, pero se puede lograr.

Comment: Hola, gracias. La version de un aplicativo está desarrollado con la version 5.6 y la otra con version 7.4. En windows 2008 server, tengo instalado las 2 versiones y no tengo este problema. En windows 2012 server, es el problema.

Comment: Visor de eventos:     Nombre de la aplicación con errores: httpd.exe, versión: 2.4.12.0, marca de tiempo: 0x54c90386
Nombre del módulo con errores: php5apache2_4.dll, versión: 5.6.8.0, marca de tiempo: 0x552ee15f
Código de excepción: 0xc0000005
Desplazamiento de errores: 0x00003500
Identificador del proceso con errores: 0x1994
Hora de inicio de la aplicación con errores: 0x01d78d2b4bd371ba

Comment: Continuacion visor de eventos:      Ruta de acceso de la aplicación con errores: C:\users\administrador\documents\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Ruta de acceso del módulo con errores: C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\xampp\php\php5apache2_4.dll
Identificador del informe: ba22fef7-fa88-11eb-80e7-20677ce121df

Comment: el error se da cuando intentas inicializar apache en un puerto que ya esta en uso.
intenta validar los puertos estan en uso con el comando: `netstat -aon`

Comment: Hola, gracias. Se cambió los puertos, el aplicativo funciona bien un tiempo de ahí muestra el mensaje. Este comando me muestra una serie conexiones activas, que se debe vericar. Unas conexiones muestran el estado listening, established,  time_wait, asociadas a un pid.

Comment: Gracias Triby, hasta le moemento me está funcionando.